# A most intriguing land

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

> There is a land where a thing turns to nothing
>   Where money is then discovered
>   Where a place becomes unknown
>   Where farming turns into a spectacle
>   Where the flora is actually worlds
>   Where a pipe can be mounted into battle
>   And where many becomes all

Where is this land?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The land is

> NOWHERE

Reasoning:

> Every line gives two definitions of two words. The second word is the first one plus one letter.

There is a land where a thing turns to nothing

> one -> **N**one (credits to @Tom)

Where money is then discovered

> fund -> f**O**und

Where a place becomes unknown

> here -> **W**here (a stretch, maybe...)

Where farming turns into a spectacle

> sow -> s**H**ow

Where the flora is actually worlds

> plants -> plan**E**ts

Where a pipe can be mounted into battle

> hose -> ho**R**se

And where many becomes all

> very -> **E**very

Comment: Well done! Every line is correct, you just have to find the first ;)

Comment: Nice question and answer! Could the first be $\tiny onetonone$.

Comment: @Keelhaul yay! Being an English language learner, getting this riddle feels quite an accomplishment to me :D

Comment: @Tom I think you're right! I'll add it to the answer

Comment: I figured the second-last might have been "rod" -> "rode".

Comment: And... we're done here. That was quick :)